# React + Express: data in server seems not passing to the frontend for some users

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I made a web game that users can create room and let other users to join. Whenever a user joins the room there should be a welcome message to the joining user himself, and a "xxx has joined" message for other users in the room. The profile pictures on the left of the room page should be updated to show profile picture of every user in the room.

I tested it with two accounts, and when user1 creates room, everything is normal. However, when user2 joins the room, everything is correctly updated in user1's page, but nothing is updated in user2's page(no welcome message, no profile picture, etc.), and the
`console.log("roomData", roomData)`
is not even logging anything in user2's page.

Here is my backend code index.js:

```
// utils
const process = require("process");
const cors = require("cors");
const socket = require("socket.io");

// imports
const verifyToken = require("./middleware/VerifyToken");
const { setUsername, join, addRoom, getRoom, deleteRoom, getCurrentUser, getUsersInRoom, leave } = require("./middleware/roomManagement");
const { newGame, updateGame, removeGame } = require("./middleware/gameManagement");

require("dotenv").config();

// express app
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const portNumber = process.env.PORT_NUMBER || 8080;

// middleware
app.use(express());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

app.use(verifyToken);

var server = app.listen(portNumber, (e) => {
    if(e) {
        console.log("Failed to start the server with error message: " + e);
    }else {
        console.log(`Web server started and running at http://localhost:${portNumber}`);
    }
});

const io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("socket connected");
    socket.on("changeName", (username) => {
        setUsername(socket.id, username);
    });

    socket.on("joinRoom", ({userId, roomId, username, isHost}) => {
        let roomData = getRoom(roomId);

        console.log("outterRoomData", roomData);
        if(roomData && roomData.inGame) {
            console.log("in if");
            socket.emit("roomData", roomData);
            return;
        }else {
            console.log("in else");
            // create user
            const curUser = join(socket.id, userId, roomId, username, isHost);
            socket.join(curUser.roomId);

            // welcome message
            socket.emit("message", {
                username: curUser.username,
                text: `Welcome, ${curUser.username}!`,
                isCipher: false
            });

            // show that the user joined
            socket.broadcast.to(curUser.roomId).emit("message", {
                username: curUser.username,
                text: `${curUser.username} has joined the room`,
                isCipher: false
            });

            const users = getUsersInRoom(curUser.roomId);

            if(roomData) {
                // update roomData for room if it alreade exist
                roomData.users = users;
            }else {
                // create room if room is not already exist
                const hostId = curUser.userId;
                const status = false;
                roomData = addRoom(roomId, users, hostId, status);
            }

            console.log("innerRoomData", roomData);
            // send roomData to client side
            io.to(curUser.roomId).emit("roomData", roomData);
        }
    });

    // start game
    socket.on("startGame", (roomId, lastLose) => {
        let room = getRoom(roomId);
        if(room) {
            // set roomData.inGame to true and send it to client side
            room.inGame = true;
            io.to(roomId).emit("roomData", room);

            const game = newGame(roomId, lastLose);
            io.to(roomId).emit("game", game);
        }
    });

    // update game status
    socket.on("game", (game) => {
        const curUser = getCurrentUser(socket.id);
        const updatedGame = updateGame(curUser.roomId, game);
        io.to(curUser.roomId).emit("game", updatedGame);
    });

    socket.on("endGame", (roomId) => {
        let room = getRoom(roomId);
        if(room) {
            // set roomData.inGame to false and sned it to client side
            room.inGame = false;
            io.to(roomId).emit("roomData", room);

            // delete game in data
            removeGame(roomId);
        }
    });

    // user sending message
    socket.on("chat", (text) => {
        const curUser = getCurrentUser(socket.id);

        io.to(curUser.roomId).emit("message", {
            username: curUser.username,
            text: text,
            isCipher: true
        });
    });

    socket.on("called", (name) => {
        const curUser = getCurrentUser(socket.id);
        io.to(curUser.roomId).emit("called", name);
    });

    // user leave the room
    socket.on("leave", () => {
        const curUser = leave(socket.id);
        if(curUser) {
            socket.leave(curUser.roomId);
            // message shows user leaving
            io.to(curUser.roomId).emit("message", {
                username: curUser.username,
                text: `${curUser.username} has left the room`
            });

            const users = getUsersInRoom(curUser.roomId);
            if(users.length == 0) {
                // delete room if there is no user in it
                deleteRoom(curUser.roomId);
            }else if(users.length > 0) {
                const room = getRoom(curUser.roomId);

                // set new host if host left
                if(room.hostId === curUser.userId) {
                    room.hostId = users[0].userId;
                    users[0].isHost = true;
                }

                // update users in room
                room.users = users;

                io.to(curUser.roomId).emit("roomData", room);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and I have Room.js in the frontend as follows:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { ClipboardCopyIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";

import { process } from "../../services/store/action";
import { to_Decrypt, to_Encrypt } from "../../utils/aes";
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import { useAutoScroll } from "../../utils/autoScroll";
import { storage } from "../../config/firebase";
import { GameArea } from "./GameArea";

export default function Room({ socket }) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [userpics, setUserpics] = useState({});
    const [hostId, setHostId] = useState("");
    const [inGame, setInGame] = useState();

    const { roomId } = useParams();
    const { setError } = useAuth();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const userRef = useAutoScroll(userpics);
    const chatRef = useAutoScroll(messages);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     // handle messages
    //     const dispatchProcess = (encrypt, msg, cipher) => {
    //         dispatch(process(encrypt, msg, cipher));
    //     };

    //     socket.on("message", (msgdata) => {
    //         // decypt the message
    //         const ans = to_Decrypt(msgdata.text, msgdata.isCipher);
    //         dispatchProcess(false, ans, msgdata.text);

    //         setMessages((prevMessages) => [
    //             ...prevMessages,
    //             {username: msgdata.username, text: ans}
    //         ]);
    //     });

    //     // display users
    //     socket.on("roomData", async (roomData) => {
    //         console.log("roomData", roomData);
    //         setHostId(roomData.hostId);
    //         setInGame(roomData.inGame);

    //         let tempPics = new Map();
    //         let tempUsers = [];
    //         await Promise.all(
    //             roomData.users.map(async (user) => {
    //                 const picRef = ref(storage, 'profilePic/' + user.userId + '.jpg');
    //                 try{
    //                     const url = await getDownloadURL(picRef);
    //                     tempPics.set(user.userId, url);
    //                     tempUsers.push(user);
    //                 }catch (e) {
    //                     console.log(e.message);
    //                 }
    //             })
    //         );
    //         setUserpics(tempPics);
    //         setUsers(tempUsers);
    //     });

    //     return () => {
    //         socket.off("message");
    //         socket.off("roomData");
    //     }
    // }, [dispatch, messages, socket]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const dispatchProcess = (encrypt, msg, cipher) => {
          dispatch(process(encrypt, msg, cipher));
        };
      
        const handleMessage = (msgdata) => {
          const ans = to_Decrypt(msgdata.text, msgdata.isCipher);
          dispatchProcess(false, ans, msgdata.text);
      
          setMessages((prevMessages) => [
            ...prevMessages,
            { username: msgdata.username, text: ans },
          ]);
        };
      
        const handleRoomData = async (roomData) => {
          console.log("roomData", roomData);
          setHostId(roomData.hostId);
          setInGame(roomData.inGame);
      
          let tempPics = new Map();
          let tempUsers = [];
          await Promise.all(
            roomData.users.map(async (user) => {
              const picRef = ref(storage, 'profilePic/' + user.userId + '.jpg');
              try {
                const url = await getDownloadURL(picRef);
                tempPics.set(user.userId, url);
                tempUsers.push(user);
              } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
              }
            })
          );
          setUserpics(tempPics);
          setUsers(tempUsers);
        };
      
        socket.on("message", handleMessage);
        socket.on("roomData", handleRoomData);
      
        return () => {
          socket.off("message", handleMessage);
          socket.off("roomData", handleRoomData);
        };
      }, [dispatch, socket]);      

    const sendData = () => {
        if(text !== "") {
            // encrypt the message
            const ans = to_Encrypt(text);
            socket.emit("chat", ans);
            setText("");
        }
    };

    const copyRoomId = () => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(roomId);
    }

    const leaveRoom = () => {
        socket.on("roomData", (roomData) => {
            setInGame(roomData.inGame);
        }); 

        if(inGame) {
            setError("Game in process, please do not leave.");
        }else {
            socket.emit("leave");
            navigate("/");
        }
    }

    const userIds = users.map(user => user.userId);

    return(
        <div>
            <div id="roomIdDisplay">Room ID: {roomId}
                <button onClick={copyRoomId}><ClipboardCopyIcon id="copyIcon" /></button>
            </div>

            <button className="logoutbutton" onClick={leaveRoom}>Leave</button>

            <div id="roomUsers" ref={userRef}>
                <div id="usersContent">
                    {userIds.map((userId, index) => {
                        const url = userpics.get(userId);
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <img src={url} alt="profilepic" className="roomProfilepic" />
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <GameArea socket={socket} roomId={roomId} users={users} host={hostId} />
            </div>

            <div id="chatBox">
                <div id="chatHistory" ref={chatRef}>
                    <div id="chatContent">
                        {messages.map((i, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index} className="message">
                                    <p>{i.username}: {i.text}</p>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sendInput">
                    <input
                        id="msgInput"
                        value={text}
                        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
                        onKeyPress={(e) => {
                            if(e.key === "Enter") {
                                sendData();
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                    <button onClick={sendData}>Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I also made sure the the socket is correctly passed to Room.js in App.js in the frontend as following:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

import './index.css';
import { AuthProvider } from "./contexts/AuthContext";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import User from "./components/account/User";
import Profile from "./components/account/Profile";
import Room from "./components/games/Room";
import JoinRoom from "./components/games/JoinRoom";
import Background from "./components/layouts/Background";
import ErrorMessage from "./components/layouts/ErrorMessage";
import WithPrivateRoute from "./utils/WithPrivateRoute";

const socket = io.connect("/");

function App() {
  const generateRoomId = () => {
    let S4 = () => {
      return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }

    return S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() +S4();
  }

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <Background />
        <ErrorMessage />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" element={
            <WithPrivateRoute>
              <Profile  socket={socket}/>
            </WithPrivateRoute>
          } />
          <Route exact path="/" element={
            <WithPrivateRoute>
              <User generateRoomId={generateRoomId} socket={socket}/>
            </WithPrivateRoute>
          } />
          <Route exact path="/join" element={
            <WithPrivateRoute>
              <JoinRoom socket={socket}/>
            </WithPrivateRoute>
          } />
          <Route path="room/:roomId" element={
            <WithPrivateRoute>
              <Room socket={socket} />
            </WithPrivateRoute>
          }/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Interest fact is that when user1 leaves room, user2's page then can be updated correctly.